# istream not working in DEV C++

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

I'm using ifstream and ofstream operations in DEV c++ but they don't seem to work correctly. I've been trying to write a little prime generator code but it doesn't work :\ When I display fstream::tellg() at any point, it displays -1:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int prime (unsigned long long n)
{   
    ifstream f1; 
    ofstream f2;             
    unsigned long long i,m,root;
    int flag=0;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {   
        f1.open("prime2.txt",ios::binary);    
        if(!f1.is_open())
        {   
            cout<<"NOT OPEN";    
        }              
        cout<<f1.tellg()<<" ";      //Displaying getpointer pos    
        flag=0;
        root=(unsigned long long)sqrt(i);
        while(f1.read((char*)&m,sizeof(m)))
        {   
            if((i%m)==0)
            {   
                flag=1;
                break;
            }      
            if(m>root)
            {   
                break;
            }                                       
        }             
        f1.close();
        if(!flag)
        {   
            f2.open("prime2.txt",ios::app|ios::binary);
            f2.write((char*)&i,sizeof(i));
            cout<<i<<" ";             //Displaying num being written
            f2.close();
        }   
    }    
    return 1;
}   

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    prime(50);
    system("pause");
}
```

(I'm sorry, i just couldn't make the whole thing get in one codeblock. I guess theres something wrong with [code] tag?)

Output:

`NOT OPEN-1 2 -1 3 -1 4 -1 5 -1 6 -1 7 -1 8 -1 9 -1 10 -1 11 -1 12 -1 13 -1 14 -1
 15 -1 16 -1 17 -1 18 -1 19 -1 20 -1 21 -1 22 -1 23 -1 24 -1 25 -1 26 -1 27 -1 2
8 -1 29 -1 30 -1 31 -1 32 -1 33 -1 34 -1 35 -1 36 -1 37 -1 38 -1 39 -1 40 -1 41
-1 42 -1 43 -1 44 -1 45 -1 46 -1 47 -1 48 -1 49 -1 50 Press any key to continue
. . .`

Comment: Please switch to a better IDE/compiler. Dev-C++ was buggy 3-4 years ago. Since then it hasn't had a single update. There is absolutely no reason to use that outmoded, buggy piece of junk. On Windows, Microsoft has a free version of their (very good) compiler and IDE in Visual C++ Express. There's also the free Code::Blocks if you want a non-Microsoft IDE. Just... don't... use.... Dev-C++.

Comment: I fixed your code block formatting - you need the four space at the beginning of every line that's to continue the block. That all said, I agree strongly with jalf - stop using Dev-C++, because it's a pile of outdated junk.

Comment: Fixed formatting for you. Indenting code with four spaces works just fine.

Comment: Yeah well i tried to use VC++, but then i saw that it had its own routines and definitions and all and i didn't want to learn everything  all over again... Basically, i need a compiler which supports __int64 on x32 comps(or x16 of possible) and is not too much diff in terms of language than Borland or Dev. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok i tried the exact code in VC++ and it worked =D. Thanx everyone!

Answer (score 3):

The return value -1 of `tellg()` [indicates failure](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/tellg/). Check that the file path is correct. Your output clearly indicates that the file cannot be opened. If a file cannot be opened, you shouldn't perform read/write operation on the file, or in this case stream.

**EDIT**

```
f1.open("prime2.txt",ios::binary);
```

Here the location of prime2.txt is relative. Since you changed compiler there is a good chance that the file cannot be found. Try with some absolute value first (like `C:\myprograms\test\prime2.txt`) and then figure out where to put prime2.txt for your program to get it by only specifying prim2.txt in `open()`.

Comment: +1. Don't for get to escape your backslashes in C++ code (regardless of the age of your compiler), though. E.g: `f1.open("C:\\myprograms\\test\\prime2.txt", ios::binary);`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing in your ouput is 'NOT OPEN'.  If file open fails, don't expect anything else to work.

Check file is present in the dir where your program executes. Try with absolute path in the filename instead of relative.

It might be better to build this logic up step by step, testing as you go, instead of writing the whole thing and then trying to debug a pile of output from failing code.

Comment: Ok, it didn't open the first time, but it does the rest of the times(ive iterated it 50 times). Then why does f.tellg() give an error even when the file has opened?

Comment: @Arpit - glad to see you got this sorted out.  Sounds like unpredictable behaviour on your  initial STL.  Really if `f1.is_open()` fails you should not use `f1` any more, `just continue;` to the next loop or `break` and exit. Sames foes for f2, where you are not currently checking the `open()` call worked.

Comment: Seems like there was something wrong with DEV. Anyway, thanx!